# What’s the best practice with JS Frameworks like Vue around using props versus global state in your components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, state, vuex

So I’m working on a bigger project with Vue and I’m curious at what the best practices are around using props versus global vuex states when accessing data for a component.

For example, if I have a component that renders a list of items, I could pass in a prop with that list of items or I could have the component look at my global state directly and avoid the props altogether. I‘m leaning towards the global state option as it removes the component dependency on its parent knowing what that list component needs access to, but the props also allow and easy pass in. What’s everyone’s thoughts here?

Comment: Any question that starts out with *"What is best practice"* then compare approach 1 to approach 2  and then just asks for thoughts is an opinion eliciting question and opinion questions are off topic here as outlined in the [help]

Answer (score 1):

As a React developer i can tell that you might use a global state solution when you need the same persisted data chunk in many components of your app. With this on mind you can avoid the props tree hell that is very hard to maintain. [image: React Redux example]

Comment: yeah, this is my thought as well. cheers